# Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated with android studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-proguard, android-studio-3.1.3

> Hello friends,
>   
>  I am facing one issue in app.gradle file when use proguard ruls with new android studio version is `3.1.3`. its working proper on old studio version `2.3.3`.
>  My full error `Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{apkData=Main{type=MAIN, fullName=debug, filters=[]}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl.`

**App.Gradle file:**
`android {
 .....................
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

Thnaks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Gradle 3.0+**

```
android {
...
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
                def flavor = variant.name
                def versionName = variant.versionName
                outputFileName = "AppName_${versionName}_${flavor}_${formattedDate}.apk"
            }
        }
    }
}
...
}
```

Result :

AppName_release_1_20200121175123.apk

Answer (score 0):

The outputFile property is not available from the variant output anymore. You should be able to get it like that:

```
def variantOutput = ...
def outputFile

try
{
    outputFile = variantOutput.outputFile
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    def packageTask = variantOutput.packageApplication
    outputFile = packageTask.outputFile
}
```